# How would I write this complex query in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want this query: for each department, find the maximum, minimum, and average number of major advisees of its faculty. List in ascending order of the maximum numbers

Comment: yes, the error will occur due to non-aggregated columns `f.id`, `m.student_id` are not listed next to `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: "for each department, find the maximum, minimum, and average number of major advisees of its faculty" If you have one department then they will have X faculty members and those faculty members will advise a total of Y students on their majors; surely the maximum, minimum and average for that department is the value Y? Or is the question badly worded and is actually asking to find the minimum, maximum and average number of advisees for **each** faculty member across that department?

Answer (score 1):

You want to aggregate twice and make sure that all the columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause are in an aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT dept_name,
       MIN( num_advisees ) AS min_advisees,
       MAX( num_advisees ) AS max_advisees,
       AVG( num_advisees ) AS avg_advisees
FROM   (
  SELECT d.dept_name,
         f.id,
         COUNT( DISTINCT m.student_id ) AS num_advisees
  FROM   department d
         INNER JOIN faculty f
         ON (d.dept_name = f.dept_name)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN major m
         ON (d.dept_name = m.dept_name AND f.id = m.advisor_id)
  GROUP BY d.dept_name, f.id
)
GROUP BY dept_name
```